# How do I show user login history?

Tags: php, laravel

I am a beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8.

I have this schema:

```
Schema::create('user_login_histories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->dateTime('date_time');
    $table->ipAddress('ip');
    $table->engine = "InnoDB";
    $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
    $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
});
```

and my Model:

```
class UserLoginHistory extends Model
{
    protected $quarded = ['id'];
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'date_time', 'ip'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    // Show User login history
    public function scopeHistory()
    {
        //return $this->hasMany('App\UserLoginHistory');
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserLoginHistory', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I want to show my user history by this function:

```
public function getLoginAdminHistory(int $idAdmin)
{   
    return UserLoginHistory::history()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(25);
}
```

but this is not working.

How can I fix this?

Comment: do you want to get only logged in user login history or all the users?

Comment: You should not create a scope on `UserLoginHistory` that references itself. Scopes are not intended to work like you are using it. Instead you should have a a `UserLoginHistory` relationship in your `User` class. Read up on `HasMany` in the Laravel documentation.

Comment: $idAdmin - this is my login ID user

Comment: You think about something like this: USER:  public function scopeHistory($userId)
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserLoginHistory', 'user_id', $userId);
    } and my function: User::history($idAdmin)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(25); ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you are using scope here is wrong. It is not meant to be used like that and will not help you with this issue, so I am not gonna go into details with that.

I am going to assume that you want to store more than one `UserLoginHistory` per `User`, so what you need is a `HasMany` relationship on the `User` class.

So to make this work, you need something like:

in `User.php`

```php
public function userLoginHistory(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserLoginHistory::class);
}
```

Now you should be able to do:
`$user->userLoginHistory`, which will return a collection of `UserLoginHistory` for you.

```php
public function getLoginAdminHistory(int $idAdmin)
{   
    $user = User::findOrFail($idAdmin);
    return $user->userLoginHistory()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(25);
}
```

Comment: How can I run this code with my user id ($idAdmin)?

Comment: That is a function on the query builder. It will find something based on an id or throw an exception if no result is found.